# Startup Disk Creator doesn't work

Tags: boot, live-usb, startup-disk-creator

I created a bootable USB stick with Startup Disk Creator in Lubuntu 16.04. Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]
<sup>**Disks**</sup>

The problem is that created USB stick is not seen during PC boot - just like there is not any flash drive inserted. Disabling UEFI security boot doesn't help. There is no such a problem when I create bootable USB stick with Universal USB Installer 1.9.6.1 in Windows. Does it look like a bug in Startup Disk Creator, or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: IS legacy-boot (CSM) in your BIOS enabled?

Comment: Thank you, @mook765, turning on legacy-boot helped to boot from the flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

> Partition type: Hidden HPFS/NTFS

The partition should be **FAT32** (FAT16 may work too). So delete it and create new one. BTW you need a bigger one then size of the disk image if you want keep persistent changes.